# Using Put request for ScienceDirect API

Tags: python, put

I am having trouble using the ScienceDirect API and looking for help.
Before I used the API with a requests.get and everything worked just fine.
Due to some alternations on my search string I am forced to use the put-method (their API support told me so).

This is my code:

```
headers = {}
headers['Accept']='application/json'
headers['X-ELS-APIKey'] = 'my Api code here'
headers['X-ELS-Insttoken'] = 'my institutional token here'
headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'


data = {
        'qs':'("blockchain" OR "distributed ledger" OR "DLT") AND ("circular economy" OR "sustainable supply chain“)',
       'offset': 0
       } 

Url = "https://api.elsevier.com/content/search/sciencedirect"

r = requests.put(Url, data =json.dumps(data), headers=headers)

print(r.url)
```

I followed the documentation here: https://dev.elsevier.com/documentation/ScienceDirectSearchAPI.wadl
When I run this code I receive the error message:

> {"service-error":{"status":
> {"statusCode":"AUTHENTICATION_ERROR","statusText":"No APIKey provided for request"}}}

My `apiKey` and the institutional token are correct and as I see it submit them in the header.
Do you have any idea why this error occurs? Am I submitting the header somehow incorrect?

Comment: EDIT: Its because of the ' symbol. If I change it to double " it works fine!

Answer (score 0):

actually this error happened bc of your website address. on the science direct you have to register your website address to get your Api_key then if you want to test your in your local system it doesn't work.
I suggest you:

1. start a django or flask project
2. set your project on port 8080
3. register your website in Sciencedirect like this: https://localhost:8080